# max() not returning largest number

Tags: python, max

I have a function that finds the odd numbers in a string, and adds them to a list of odd numbers, I then use max() on the list to find the largest odd number but it seems to limit itself to 99, eg.

```
def largest_odd():
    userInput = input(' enter 10 integers separated by a space').split(' ')
    oddList = []

    for x in userInput:
        if int(x) % 2 > 0:
            oddList.append(x)
            print(x, ' is odd')
        else:
            print(x, ' is not odd')
    return max(oddList) 

largest_odd()
```

Now, if I enter `'1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'`, it will return 9 as the highest.

If I enter `'1 2 3 4 5 20175'`

It will return `5` as the highest.

Comment: You have a list of *strings*, not numbers. You only convert to `int` temporarily, for the modulo operation.

Comment: ahhh, ok I ammended it to oddList.append(int(x)) and now it works, thanks!

Comment: @timgeb thats because you added the quotations. Try and input the actual integers separately.

Comment: Have you tried printing the list after input. That should be the first step of debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your corrected code:

```
def largest_odd():
    userInput = input(' enter 10 integers separated by a space').split(' ')
    oddList = []

    for x in userInput:
        if int(x) % 2 > 0:
            oddList.append(int(x))
            print(x, ' is odd')
        else:
            print(x, ' is not odd')

    return max(oddList)

print(largest_odd())
```